# Get-EventLog -After query

Tags: powershell

When I run the below command on powershell one by one, then I am getting the expected result. However when I run it as a PS script, I am not getting any output.

```
$StartDate = Get-Date

Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "MsiInstaller" -EventId 11707 -Message "Product: Installation operation completed successfully."

Get-EventLog Application -After "$StartDate" -Source "MsiInstaller"
```

What is missing?

Comment: Is powershell allowed to execute scripts ? (try `get-executionPolicy` )

Answer (score 0):

It's the accuracy of the event log, when you run it in a script, it all happens in the same second.

try this:

```
$StartDate = Get-Date

Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "MsiInstaller" -EventId 11707 -Message "Product: Installation operation completed successfully."

start-sleep(1)

Get-EventLog Application -After "$StartDate" -Source "MsiInstaller"
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're actually trying to do. This seems like just a part of the problem.

Comment: I am capturing the datetime before installation of inhouse product. After installation of the same products; I want to find out the MisInstaller events generated in between time interval. For the same I am simulating code. In the same code, if I use -newest 2 (for example) post sleep command; it works. However for -After switch it did't. Have you tried it to run as PS script. Because individual line works.